# Looping through a list of regex matches and grabbing the first capture group in a loop

Tags: regex

I am trying to loop through regex results, and insert the first capture group into a variable to be processed in a loop. But I can't figure out how to do so. Here's what I have so far, but it just prints the second match:

```
aQuote = "The big boat has a big assortment of big things."
theMatches = regmatches(aQuote, gregexpr("big ([a-z]+)", aQuote ,ignore.case = TRUE))

results = lapply(theMatches, function(m){
    capturedItem = m[[2]]
    print(capturedItem)
})
```

Right now it prints

```
[1] "big assortment"
```

What I want it to print is

```
[1] boat
[1] assortment
[1] things
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
regmatches(aQuote, gregexpr("(?<=big )[a-z]+", aQuote ,ignore.case = TRUE,perl=TRUE))[[1]]
#[1] "boat"       "assortment" "things"
```

Answer (score 1):

Include `g` (global) modifier in you code as well.
Equivalent regex in perl / javascript is: `/big ([a-z]+)/ig`

Sample perl prog:

```
$aQuote =  "The big boat has a big assortment of big things.";
print $1."\n" while ($aQuote =~ /big ([a-z]+)/ig);
```

JS Fiddle [here](https://regex101.com/r/aG4cH4/1).

**Edit:** In `r`, we can write:

```
aQuote = "The big boat has a big assortment of big things."
theMatches = regmatches(aQuote, gregexpr("big ([a-z]+)", aQuote ,ignore.case = TRUE))

results = lapply(theMatches, function(m){
    len= length(m)
    for (i in 1:len)
    {
        print(m[[i]])
    }
})
```

`r` fiddle [here](https://ideone.com/BMHf9O).

Comment: ohk! I dont know about `r`, but the code snippet provided by me in `perl` works well

Comment: That is in `perl`, not `r`. I can do this super easy in `php` since global match for a regex match returns a 2 dimensional array. `r` is where I am having difficulty.

Comment: @slickrickulicious added edit to support r language. Please check, I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @KamalNayan That still prints results like "big boat". I want it to print only "boat" or "assorted" or "things"